# elements property without form or fieldset tags

Tags: javascript, html, forms, sharepoint, element

Problem:

As I'm working with Sharepoint I can't use the  `<form>` tag to wrap around my form and i've used `<fieldset>` as a dirty workaround.
When I try to call all Input Elements of the fieldset, there is the next problem:

[IE 11 does not seem to support the `elements` property on `HTMLFieldSetElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFieldSetElement) and  conveniently this is exactly what most Users at my place use.

Question:

**What other options do I have to wrap the forms so I can call `form.elements`?
(Without using `<form>` or `<fieldset>` ?**

Comment: And the fieldsets are populated with all kind of elements, not just with control elements?

Comment: only `input` and `label`

Comment: Why to stick to a non-working property then, just read all the input tags from the fieldsets ..?

Comment: I need .`elements` or I have to rewrite everything for it to work in IE, does any other tag support this functionality?

Comment: Afaik `form` is the only tag supporting `elements`, but I didn't know `fieldset` supporting it too in other browsers. You could add the property to the HTMLFieldElement prototype in IE, though monkey patching is not the first recommended thing to do.

Comment: I've used your aproach and now i've got a `HTMLCollection()` of said Items, now, before I used 
`var formToJSON = function formToJSON(elements) {
  return [].reduce.call(elements, function (data, element) { ....`   How do I pass the single elements of that collection to the function? Thank you for your help!

Comment: `element` argument in your example callback function is supposed to be the current value in the iteration.